# In Gizmos (2nd ed.), if someone performs the "research action" and files a gizmo, does that count as a "file action"?

Tags: gizmos

For example, if someone decides to research on the first turn, if they decide to put a card in their archive, would they then draw an energy at random (from the beginning gizmo that allows you to do so whenever you perform a file action)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes

> RESEARCH
> Choose any facedown Level Deck (1, 2, or 3) and draw a
>   number of cards equal to your Research Amount. You may not
>   draw from more than 1 Level Deck at a time. Each player starts the
>   game with a Research Amount of 3, but some Upgrade Gizmos
>   may increase that number.
>   If there are fewer cards in the chosen Level Deck than your Research Amount,
>   draw only the number of cards available.
>   After you draw the cards, choose 1 of them and either Build it (if you have
>   enough Energy) or File it (if you have space in your Archive). Or, you can choose to
>   do neither.
>   Return the remaining cards facedown to the bottom of the corresponding
>   Level Deck, in the order of your choosing. You may return all drawn cards to the
>   bottom if you wish, or if you can’t File or Build any of them.
>   **Note: The File or Build Action you perform during a Research Action also
>   counts to trigger active Gizmos (see Triggering Gizmo Effects below).**[bolding added]

https://cmon-files.s3.amazonaws.com/pdf/assets_item/resource/126/Rulebook_Gizmos.pdf